# Searching Log Table with Multiple Dimensions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find a more performance way to search a log table. The table logs all searches performed on a site, and can contain multiple filters on a single criteria. For example, users can search for homes in multiple counties, and multiple property types on a single search. I need to be able to run a report to find how many users searched within a specific county/counties with a specific property type/types. The searches are currently logged in the following tables:

Stores the dimension definitions for a search:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogSearchDimensions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VarName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Label] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LogSearchDimensions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Example data:

```
ID          VarName                                            Label
----------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
3           City_ID                                            City ID
5           County_ID                                          County ID
7           PageNum                                            Page Number
8           PriceLow                                           Lowest Price
9           PriceHigh                                          Highest Price
10          Region_ID                                          Region ID
11          Site_ID                                            Site ID
14          AcreLow                                            Lowest Acreage
15          AcreHigh                                           Highest Acreage
16          State_ID                                           State ID
17          Style                                              Style
18          SiteStateID                                        Site State ID
19          Distance                                           Distance
20          FIPS                                               FIPS Code
```

Stores the primary search information, such as when a search was performed, and who performed it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogSearches](
    [ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RecordCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PageNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IPAddress] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Domain] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ScriptName] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [QueryString] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Referer] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
    [SearchString] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [UserAgent] [nvarchar](2048) NULL,
    [Processed] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IntegerIP] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LogSearches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Stores the dimensions for each search. This could be a single record, or 50, depending on the search that was performed:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogSearchesDimensions](
    [ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogSearch_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [LogSearchDimension_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SearchValue] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LogSearchesDimensions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogSearchesDimensions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LogSearchesDimensions_LogSearchDimensions] FOREIGN KEY([LogSearchDimension_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LogSearchDimensions] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogSearchesDimensions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LogSearchesDimensions_LogSearchDimensions]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogSearchesDimensions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LogSearchesDimensions_LogSearches] FOREIGN KEY([LogSearch_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LogSearches] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogSearchesDimensions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LogSearchesDimensions_LogSearches]
GO
```

In the LogSearchesDimensions table, I could have multiple records for County_ID (LogSearchDimension_id 5) if the user searched for more than one county in a single search. Let's assume the user searched in counties 5, 6, 7, 12, and 15. When I'm running a report, this single search would need to show up in the reports for all 5 counties that were searched. If I ran a report that combined counties 5 and 6, then it should only show once.

I know this is a lot of information, and probably still not enough, but I'm hoping someone who's done similar could share some tips for making this type of filter work with some degree of speed.

I currently have a very complicated query, with all sorts of joins and having conditions to try and find searches with the proper number of matches, but it's not performing well at all. I've attached a diagram of the tables to show the relationships.[image]
<sub>(source: [dansshorts.com](http://www.dansshorts.com/searchdiagram.png))</sub>

I'm currently searching using the following methods:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwLogSearchesCounty]
AS
SELECT     dbo.LogSearches.ID, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dbo.LogSearches.Created AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS Created, C.county, C.County_ID, S.state, S.state_ID
FROM         dbo.LogSearches WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                      dbo.LogSearchesDimensions AS D WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.LogSearches.ID = D.LogSearch_ID AND D.LogSearchDimension_ID = 5 INNER JOIN
                      propertyControlCenter.dbo.county AS C WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.County_ID = D.SearchValue INNER JOIN
                      propertyControlCenter.dbo.state AS S WITH (nolock) ON C.state_ID = S.state_ID


DECLARE @LowDate DATETIME, @HighDate DATETIME;   
SET @LowDate = '2010-01-01'  ;   
SET @HighDate = '2010-02-01' ;         
SELECT     
    CONVERT(varchar, Created, 107) AS displayDate     
    , County     , County_ID     
    , reportCount    
FROM (     
    SELECT      
        Created      
        , County_ID      , County      , reportCount      
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MaxRecords DESC, County) AS theRank     
        FROM (      
            SELECT       
                v.County_ID               
                , v.Created              
                , C.county + ' County, ' + S.State_Code AS County       
                , COUNT(DISTINCT v.ID) AS reportCount       
                , MAX(COUNT(DISTINCT v.ID)) OVER(PARTITION BY v.County_ID) AS MaxRecords      
            FROM       
                vwLogSearchesCounty v (NOLOCK)       
                INNER JOIN propertyControlCenter.dbo.county C (NOLOCK) ON        
                    v.County_ID = C.County_ID        
                    AND v.Created BETWEEN @LowDate AND @HighDate                 
                    AND c.State_ID = 48         
                INNER JOIN propertyControlCenter.dbo.state S (NOLOCK) ON C.state_ID = S.state_ID       
                INNER JOIN LogSearchesDimensions D (NOLOCK) ON v.ID = D.LogSearch_ID AND D.LogSearchDimension_ID IN (8, 9, 14, 15, 17)      
                WHERE       
                    1 = 0               
                    OR (         
                        D.LogSearchDimension_ID = 17         
                        AND D.SearchValue IN (2,5,6 )        
                    )             
                GROUP BY               
                    v.Created              
                    , v.County_ID       
                    , C.County       
                    , S.State_Code              
                HAVING COUNT(v.ID) >=  3       ) d     
                GROUP BY      
                    Created      
                    , County      
                    , County_ID      
                    , reportCount      
                    , MaxRecords     ) 
                ranking     
                WHERE theRank <= 5     
ORDER BY theRank, County_ID, Created
```

Current record counts:
LogSearches: 8,970,000
LogSearchesDimensions: 37,630,000

The above query takes 24 seconds to run (too long for our purposes) and returns the following data:

```
displayDate                    County                                                                                                                                                                                                            County_ID   reportCount
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
Jan 01, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        49
Jan 02, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        84
Jan 03, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        76
Jan 04, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        118
Jan 05, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        92
Jan 06, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        59
Jan 07, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        45
Jan 08, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        84
Jan 09, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        71
Jan 10, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        91
Jan 11, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        67
Jan 12, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        52
Jan 13, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        76
Jan 14, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        104
Jan 15, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        69
Jan 16, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        51
Jan 17, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        105
Jan 18, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        76
Jan 19, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        72
Jan 20, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        69
Jan 21, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        32
Jan 22, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        54
Jan 23, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        60
Jan 24, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        76
Jan 25, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        95
Jan 26, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        73
Jan 27, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        64
Jan 28, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        57
Jan 29, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        41
Jan 30, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        87
Jan 31, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        67
Feb 01, 2010                   Bastrop County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6218        66
Jan 01, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        51
Jan 02, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        70
Jan 03, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        69
Jan 04, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        74
Jan 05, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        44
Jan 06, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        60
Jan 07, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        37
Jan 08, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        39
Jan 09, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        40
Jan 10, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        71
Jan 11, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        63
Jan 12, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        54
Jan 13, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        51
Jan 14, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        46
Jan 15, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        54
Jan 16, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        45
Jan 17, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        73
Jan 18, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        70
Jan 19, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        30
Jan 20, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        57
Jan 21, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        59
Jan 22, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        43
Jan 23, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        49
Jan 24, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        72
Jan 25, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        86
Jan 26, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        43
Jan 27, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        69
Jan 28, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        57
Jan 29, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        46
Jan 30, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        52
Jan 31, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        107
Feb 01, 2010                   Montgomery County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                             6199        40
Jan 01, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        58
Jan 02, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        65
Jan 03, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        50
Jan 04, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        61
Jan 05, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        52
Jan 06, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        48
Jan 07, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        44
Jan 08, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        40
Jan 09, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        25
Jan 10, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        56
Jan 11, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        51
Jan 12, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        47
Jan 13, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        43
Jan 14, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        47
Jan 15, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        43
Jan 16, 2010                   Fayette County, TX                                                                                                                                                                                                6240        37
Jan 17, 2010                   Fayette County, TX
```

Comment: Good problem information, but what's the actual problem/question?

Comment: Could you give us some example queries and their performance?  That would help.

Comment: The problem is how to search it with any degree of performance... I'll edit with an example query, and some row counts as well.

Comment: I've tried to add the execution plan, but for some reason it won't take...

Comment: Well, I have been looking at it but it's pretty hard to analyze on syntax alone.  Is there any possibility that you could save the Execution Plan in XML format (.SQLPLAN) and then post on the internet somewhere that I could look at it?

Comment: Hmm, after preliminary anlaysis, it is now clear that the County and State tables are very important to the performance of this query, so we will need their complete Definitions also (including, any Keys, FKs and indexes)

Comment: You can email me the SQLPLAN if you want.  I am at Gmail.com and my username is the same as it is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preliminary Performance Analysis:

### Principal Observaton And Recommendation:

It appears that

1. this is a Data Warehouse (everything presented is consistent with a DW), and
2. it has been implemented in a SQL Server OLTP database.

Therefore, the best thing you could do would be to :

#### 0. Re-implement it in a SQL Server OLAP Database:

OLAP databases (or Analysis Services or SSAS) are much better suited for this kind of application and much better optimized for this kind of query.  However, on the assumption that this would be far beyond the scope of your current intentions, I will proceed with lower impact recommendations.

### Preliminary Observations and Recommendations:

*these are necessarily preliminary as real performance analysis cannot be done on something this complex without at least an estimated query plan.  In particular, although recommendations for **possible** improvements can be made, without the real data, or query plans based on the real data, it is impossible to tell which changes will actually make any real difference in performance.*

The basic problem that I see is that this very complex query is doing a lot of full-table scans and because of its complexity is almost effectively *forcing* these scans.  Table scans can be very expensive, especially on large tables.  However, if there is no effective way for SQL to pre-filter a table (that is, to eliminate 99% of the records via a test that does not require a join and can be applied to an index), then that is the most efficient choice that it has left.  In that light, the following recommendations look at ways to remedy that situation:

#### A. Make a SARGable [Created] column on the [vwLogSearchesCounty] View.

Currently the [vwLogSearchesCounty] View defines its [Created] column like this:

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dbo.LogSearches.Created AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS Created
```

The apparent reason for this is to allow the use of the BETWEEN operator on this column when searching for Date Ranges, without have to worry about the problems of time-of-day mismatches.  However this has the side-effect of making this column non-SARGable, that is, not searchable via an index ("SARG" = "Search ARGument").  As the searches on this column are one of the few globally-fixed constraints (that is, something that can be searched on *before* doing joins) making it SARGable is one of your best oppurtunities for speeding up your queries.

To make it SARGable, you need to do the following:

1. Either remove the CAST(FLOOR(CAST(..))) function from the [Created] column or add a second column to the view without them (I will assume the later) like this:

   ```
   dbo.LogSearches.Created AS CreatedTime
   ```
2. Change the Date-Range search in the view, as below, from

   ```
   AND v.Created BETWEEN @LowDate AND @HighDate
   ```

   to

   ```
   AND v.CreatedTime >= @LowDate AND v.CreatedTime < dateadd(dd,1,@HighDate)
   ```
3. Make sure that there is an Index on the original [Created] column.  A clustered index would be best:

   ```
   CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_LogSearches_Created ON [dbo].[LogSearches] (Created)
   ```

(for more on correctly searching for dates and date ranges in SQL Server see here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic438717-338-1.aspx)

#### B. Make [LogSearchDimension_ID] column in the [LogSearchesDimensions] table Indexed.

I do not know if this column is already indexed, but it should be as it is another of the very few globally-fixed constraints.  Again, a clustered index would be best:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_LogSearchesDimensions_11 ON [dbo].[LogSearchesDimensions] ([LogSearchDimension_ID])
```

#### C. Make [State_code] column on the [State] table Indexed.

Like (B) above, it may not be indexed, but your query would probably benefit if it was.

#### D.  Eliminate the explicit [County] and [State] tables from your query.

It appears that the only reason that you are explicitly joining the [County] and [State] tables in your query is to get the [State_Code] column from the [State] table that is not included in the [vwLogSearchesCounty] view.  Ideally, the optimizer would figure out that it could merge these two references to the [State] and [County] tables together and you could pick up that column for free.  Unfortunately the optimizer often misses such things on more complex queries, and on my server it appears to be doing double work for this field.

The best solution would be to just add the [State_code] column to the view and then eliminate the explicit [county] and [State] joins in your query.  this additional colum should *not* affect the performance of any other queries that use the view but do not use this column (SQL Server 2005 and above).

***If you implement all four of these recommendations (including the CLUSTERED part) you should be able to elminate the table scans.  At this time I see no other reasonable way to do so.***

### More Desparate Recommendation:

If all of this should fail to help you, I can only see one other relatively low-cost option, which is to turn your View [vwLogSearchesCounty], into an Indexed View.  In particular, the Indexes that I mentioned above on [State_Code] and [Created]/[CreatedTime] should be reimplemented on the View (as well as any other important ones).

This has the effect, not only of indexing important fields, but also of pre-aggregating the View and automatically maintaining that pre-aggregation.  This also means that it will take up storage space, so if this view has a very large number of rows, that may be an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll play some with some of these options on Monday and see if I can squeeze some more juice out of the server :).

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see that I was joining the county and state tables twice. Removing the double INNER JOINs from the SELECT and relying on just the ones in the view seems to have made a large impact (obviously). I also changed the Created date item and created another column with the formatted Date that I'll need for grouping. The query is now running in 5 seconds instead of more than 20. Thanks for the second pair of eyes and the suggestions.